# Showing a loading message whilst JavaScript code is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some particularly slow jQuery code which executes when a button is clicked. I'd like to show a loading message/spinner whilst it executes. Something like so:

```
$('#some_button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#spinner').show();
  really_slow_function();
  $('#spinner').hide();
});
```

I do this all the time when waiting for an response following an ajax request but not sure what to do in this instance. The `really_slow_function` isn't obscenely inefficient, it's just doing some dom manipulation and mobile devices take a while to get it done.

The problem with code in the example is that the spinner never shows. I assume it's because JavaScript isn't doing anything until the function finishes.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Show the code of really_slow_function

Comment: Even if you could show the spinner, it wouldn't spin since the code is using the UI thread. See http://jsfiddle.net/M5YGs/

Comment: OP, did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function really_slow_function(callback) {
  var a = new Date();

  while (new Date() - a < 5000);
  callback.call(this);
}


$('#some_button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#spinner').fadeIn(function() {
    really_slow_function(function() {
      $('#spinner').fadeOut();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#spinner {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="spinner" src="http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif">
<button id="some_button">click</button>
```

From this

http://jsfiddle.net/M5YGs/7/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#some_button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#spinner').show();

  setTimeout(function() {
      really_slow_function();
      $('#spinner').hide();
  }, 50);
});
```

By slightly delaying the execution of the slow function with a timeout there should be enough space for the dom to update.